# CompoujdJS Generators Missing

Tags: node.js, compoundjs

I am new to compoundjs and have started creating helloworld samples for compoundjs.

I tried to use the default generators, but in my app the only available generator is `app`,
the rest like `controller`, `model` are missing.

Below is the output when i type `compound` in terminal

```
Usage: compound command [argument(s)]

Commands:
  h,  help                Display usage information
  i,  init                Initialize compound app
  g,  generate [smth]     Generate something awesome
  r,  routes [filter]     Display application routes
  c,  console             Debug console
  s,  server [port]       Run compound server
  x,  install [module]    Install compound module
  sd, seed plant|harvest  Populate database with seed data
  db, db [migrate|update] Migrate or update database(s)

Available generators:

  app
```

What am i doing wrong? Please suggest.

**FYI :** My compound version is `1.1.0`

Comment: Are you actually in a compoundjs project directory? It looks like it only lists app as the only generator if not. Have you tried using another generator (e.g. `compound generate controller test actionOne`)? Are there errors?
https://github.com/compoundjs/generators

Comment: actually i installed a missing module `co-generators` and this fixed the issue, but i am wondering all these modules should be default, and not sure why i need to do this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

Added missing module `co-generators` in package.json and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was elsewhere. I had to remove all my custom code until I found the problem in `autoload.js` which had two `module.exports = function()` definitions. After moving my custom module to `defaultModules` and removing the 2nd `function()`, compound correctly returned the installed generators.